# bcryptjs comparePassword always returns false - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I have looked at the other answers to the question on here but still not getting anywhere. I cannot get the `comparePassword` function to return true

```
module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
      newUser.password = salt;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
};

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
  console.log("Provided password is " + candidatePassword);
  console.log("Provided hash is " + hash);
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
    if(err) throw err;
      console.log(isMatch);
      callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

So if we take the user in test at this stage you can see their data

```
{ _id: 5aec6f702a4a181f261a43fe,
  full_name: 'Its me',
  username: 'myusername',
  email: 'myemail@gmail.com',
  tel_number: '12345678',
  password: '$2a$10$6GCgZDt.FL/eeZ1NsDASe.', // text version = test
  __v: 0
}
```

When `comparePassword` is run the console logs return

```
Provided password is test
Provided hash is $2a$10$6GCgZDt.FL/eeZ1NsDASe.
```

So to me they match right?

Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Is the problem in `newUser.password = salt;` instead of `newUser.password = hash;`?

Comment: @Nick certainly was... Thank You... You know when you just stare at something for an hour and just cant work it out... haha... thanks again

Comment: Hi Rich. I'm a volunteer editor here, and we try to trim and tidy questions as much as we can. We value brevity here, since it saves us a good bit of work. I often paste the following piece of advice:

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try replacing the line `newUser.password = salt;` with `newUser.password = hash;` ?

And let us know if that works.

I have an example in my github repo, it might help

https://github.com/shirshendubhowmick/jwt-demo

Here is a snippet of the code from the repo

```
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (error, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (error, hash) => {
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Shirshendu, would you mind including the code from your github repo inline with the answer? That way your answer will still be useful even if the link to your github breaks. Thanks